# Run an .exe file on apache?

Tags: apache, cgi, exe

I'm trying to run a cgi executable file through a html form as in this code:

```
 <html>

 <head>
<title>CGI Form</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
<form action="C:\WWW\cgi-bin\y.exe" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="string1" />
    <input type="text" name="string2" />
    <input type="text" name="string3" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

And here it is the cgi code compiled as y.exe and saved in the path specified in the action:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
char *buffer, string1[100], string2[100], string3[100], merged[300]; 

buffer = getenv("QUERY_STRING"); 

if(buffer == NULL) 
{
    printf("<p>Error: No data</p>");
}
else
{
    if(sscanf(buffer, "string1=%s&string2=%s&string3=%s", string1, string2, string3) !=      3) 
    {
        printf("Data missing!");
    }
    else
    {   
        strcpy(merged, string1); 
        strcat(merged, string2); 
        strcat(merged, string3); 

        printf("Content-Type: text/html\n\n");
        printf("<html>\n"
               "<head>\n"
                   "<title>CGI Form Merge Strings</title>\n"
               "</head>\n"
               "<body>\n"
                   "Merged string is: %s\n"
               "</body>\n"
               "</html>\n", merged);  
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

I've tried to reconfigure the httpd.conf file with this:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .exe
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/WWW/cgi-bin/"
```

and

```
<Directory "C:/WWW/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options +ExecCGI
    Options FollowSymLinks 
    Require all granted
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    AddHandler cgi-script .exe
</Directory>
```

However this does not fix the problem.

Comment: Is cgi module loaded in apache? Make sure, that this line is not commented: `LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so`

Comment: No it is not commented. Id doesn't start with #.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
action="C:\WWW\cgi-bin\y.exe"
```

You need to give an HTTP URI here. It will probably be:

```
action="/cgi-bin/y.exe"
```

Comment: Even this does not fix the problem. It asks me to download the file. What I want is to make the browser to interpret it as a html code. This requires some configurations but I don't know what to try.