# Golang CGI on apache

Tags: apache, go

I am trying to run Golang cgi scripts through apache. I can get the files compiled and am using examples i found of how to make it, but I don't know what file extension to add to apache's "add handler" or if that is even where I should tell apache to handle the Go compiled source. Currently when you go to the cgi-bin file in a web browser you just download the Unix Executable File.
as you can see I have tried .exe and .go neither of which I expected to work, and didn't.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/cgi">
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py .exe .go
    AllowOverride All
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Also, does cgi vs cgi matter? I have been using both to see which ones work, but neither do with my current configuration.

Comment: go is compiled language. Don't re-compile the same code for every access. Use the compiled result (.exe on Windows) as your cgi. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325054/run-an-exe-file-on-apache

Comment: Rather than starting up a new process for each "cgi" fetch wouldn't it be better to leave a real Go web server running (doing all the Go based stuff you want in a single server) and just arrange to have the appropriate URLs directed to it (e.g. via Apache's config)? Alternatively, maybe [`net/http/fcgi`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/fcgi/).

Comment: I am sorry Maybe I was not clear since I put .exe in the config, but I am running it on linux, and am not compiling it overtime, I compiled it into a Unix Executable File but am not sure how to add that type of file to apache.

I really want the go to handle operations on like web forms and such, probably sent from javascript, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Some servers allow executing cgi programs outside of cgi-bin, other servers require them in cgi-bin folder. The permissions must be set correctly (i.e. 755 or other)

if you do decide to execute cgi programs outside of cgi-bin and your server allows it, this may be a security issue

On many servers you don't need to add handlers for the main cgi-bin folder, you just need to set file permissions by ftp or telnet. If you are downloading the file rather than executing it, are you sure permissions is set correct using an ftp program? Try 755, 777, and others

Note: a go program is not a script, it's a compiled executable.   With a binary program, you don't need an interpreter so your server could be confused as to what a go program needs to be interpreted as. You just want to run it with exec permissions , not interpret it as a script.

Migrating servers can be a nightmare if you don't stick to standard cgi-bin folder design. Some servers don't allow all apache config modifications due to security or other concerns, so when you change hosting plans one day all your programs and folder structures could be broken if you use non standard config hacks.

Some servers even require them to be run in jails, which complicates matters further. Figure out how your server is setup and what it allows, and study what permissions are required to execute.